# netlify redirect rule not applying

Tags: node.js, reactjs, netlify

I have the following configuration in my `_redirects` file:

```
/*  /index.html  200
https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect/*  https://mysite.app/.netlify/functions/gaProxy/:splat  200
```

The rule for Google Analytics won't be executed. I can see in the inspection view of my browser, that the request is still going to https://region1.google-analytics.com/...

Why?